# Mask items in recycler view with drawable (background)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, background

Is there a simple way of masking items in a recycler view?
I made a drawable solid with a gray stroke and a corner radius of 20.
The strokes looks good on top/bot/sides but the rounded corners get cut of bu the recycler items.

Is there a common practise to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I can increase the padding but I don't want adjust for it in later on.

Maybe I could make the background transparent, but the dividers would still go beyond the corners. 

The Ideal way would be to have some kind of masking option in the XML-file. So far I haven't found any.

Comment: how they are cut? do you have any image?

Comment: can you post some screenshots of the problem you mentioned? any visual way to represent how you want it to be may also be helpful for giving answer

Comment: Added an image.

Comment: Is there any elevation applied to your recycler View? It looks like Zindex problem for me. I'd try to set `android:transformZ="5dp"` or anything higher than your RV elevation.

Comment: Are you using `DividerItemDecoration`?

Comment: No, I am however setting the padding to 5 in my background XML.
Maybe that could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across the same problem, i know this answer is 8 months late, but i'll still provide what i came up with.

For my RecyclerView, in which i already have icons with round corners, i used this as background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="40dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="480dp"
        android:height="480dp"/>
    <solid
        android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
</shape>
```

And then, i used this as foreground (it worked like a mask):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="40dp"
        />
    <size
        android:width="500dp"
        android:height="500dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="10dp"
        android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
</shape>
```

You can then play on the thickness of the outline, and add some padding to the RecyclerView.

Hope this helps, ^_^.

Happy Coding;